# Range of Iterated Projectile Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, collision, projectile

This is the question :

> Superman is throw inside one end of a room whose floor is made of kryptonite, his only weakness. He tries to fly using his mighty powers with an initial velocity $V_0$ at an angle $30^\circ$ with the floor. But he is weakened by the floor and so falls and he repeats the same to reach the exit at the other end of the room. The weaker he is, the more vulnerable he gets. This can be approximated as a projectile motion having variable coefficient of restitution for the $n^{\text{th}}$ collision with the floor, $e_n=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}$. The the minimum length of the room so that superman does not escape is

From what I've learnt I just need to equate the length of the room, say $L$ is greater than the total range said.

Here, the range after collision would be $e_n R$

So,

\begin{align}
L &= R_0 + e_1 R_0 + e_2 R_0 + \dots + e_n R_0\\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{3}v_0^2}{2g} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4}{9} + \dots + \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\right)
\end{align}

and then I'm stuck. This is the solution given:

> Range for the first projectile is $R_1=\frac{\sqrt{3}v_0^2}{2g}\left(\frac{u^2\sin\theta}{g}\right)$
>
> but $R_2=e_1R_1=\frac{\sqrt{3}V_0^2}{2g}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);\quad R_2=e_1e_2R_1=\frac{\sqrt{3}v_0^2}{2g}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)$ 
> $\therefore\sum_{i=1}^\infty R_i = \frac{\sqrt{3}v_0^2}{2g}\left(1+\frac14+\frac19+\dots+\infty\right)$ 
> We know $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3_0^1}+\dfrac{x^5}{5_0^1}+\dots+\infty$ 
> also roots of their equation are $0,\pm\pi,\pm,\ne2\pi\dots$ 
> $\therefore$ we can write $\sin x=x\!\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\!\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)\!\left(1=\dfrac{x^2}{9\pi^2}\right)\dots$ 
> from this coefficient of $x^3$ is $-\left(\frac{1}{\pi^2}+\frac{1}{4\pi^2}+\frac{1}{9\pi^2}+\dots\right)$ 
> $\therefore -\frac16=-\left(\frac{1}{\pi^2}+\frac{1}{4\pi^2}+\frac{1}{9\pi^2}+\dots\right);\quad\therefore\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\dots\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ 
> This is a very famous and beautiful equation.

First off, the solution showed $\frac19$ instead of $\frac49$, and I'm not sure how that is. Then I don't quite understand bringing out the $\sin x$ equation nor did I understand how the came intead of the respective denominators.

Can anyone explain it to me, or at least tell me the derivation of the $\sin x$?

Comment: *the solution showed 1/9 instead of 4/9 and Im not sure how that is* $R_3=e_2R_2=e_1e_2R_1=\tfrac19R_1$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have the wrong formula for the distance from each collision. The coefficient of restitution relates each distance to the previous distance, not the initial distance. This gives us a recursion relation for $R_n$:
$$R_n = e_n R_{n-1}$$
From this, we can derive an explicit formula for $R_n$:
$$R_n = R_0 \prod_{i=1}^n e_i$$

---

The first formula given for $\sin x$ is its Maclaurin series, which is presented to justify thinking of $\sin x$ as polynomial. Then, knowing its roots to be given by $n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can factor this "polynomial" into
$$\sin x = x\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$
The basic idea behind this formula is that any polynomial $P(x)$, with roots at $a_n$ can by expressed as
$$P(x) \propto \prod_n \left(1-\frac{x}{a_n}\right)$$
The slight difference between this and the formula above comes from combining positive and negative roots with the difference of squares formula.